# git: change location of files in branch AKA branch a subfolder

Tags: git, branch, github-pages

I want a branch to hold only some directory of my master. Is it possible while preserving the git metadata between the files?

in practice: my master is as follows

```
/src
  + myfile.1
  + myfile.2
/libs
  + submodule Y
/docs
  + index.html
  + css
```

and I want a new branch (gh-pages ;) to hold only the *content* of docs/ directory, and not the directory itself... while keeping the link for easier further sync.

a classical `git checkout master -- docs/index.html` from within gh-pages branch does not seem to allow me to move the file to /index.html while preserving its link to the original docs/index.html

Any clue/pointer how to do this? (and update from master afterwards)

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use a branch as if it was a submodule...

Comment: You could try moving src, libs, and docs into separate repos, then building a super project with subtrees.  That would let you have branches in each individual repo.